# Firebase User Login Failed with invalid Email com.google.firebase.auth not found

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

My `LoginActivity` contains `EditText`s for user to input their email and password. All codes seems OK to me.

However, after clicking the login button, the user does not login.  It turns out that the email is invalid, in which the `EditText` of email contains as following:

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{b014ce3 VFED..CL. .F...... 56,646-1384,804 #7f0d0096 app:id/etEmailLogin}
```

Please help me to find what's wrong.

```
package com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private EditText etEmailLogin;
    private EditText etPasswordLogin;

    private Button bLogin;
    private Button bSwitchToRegister;
    private Button bResetPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, (findViewById(R.id.etEmailLogin)).toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth         firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        etEmailLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailLogin);
        etPasswordLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordLogin);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
        bSwitchToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSwitchToRegister);
        bSwitchToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        bResetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResetPassword);
        bResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO:     com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.ConfirmRecoverPasswordActivity
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    public void signIn() {
        final String passwordl = etPasswordLogin.toString().trim();
        final String emaill = etEmailLogin.toString().trim();

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, user.getEmail()+"; "+    (findViewById(R.id.etEmailLogin)).toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, emaill);

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emaill, passwordl);
        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    };
}
```

And my `LoginActivity` Layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app.LoginActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your Email"
        android:id="@+id/etEmailLogin"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLogin"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not registered yet? Click here for redistration!"
        android:id="@+id/bSwitchToRegister"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:textColor="#0a68ec"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:foreground="#0000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forget password? Click here to reset your password!"
        android:id="@+id/bResetPassword"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textColor="#ed7a41"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="#0000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

following message:

```
09-11 03:00:24.280 32751-32751/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[WelcomeActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=205.09277, y[0]=2066.7188, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=20468343, downTime=20463897, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 03:00:24.521 32751-32751/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app D/LoginActivity: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{b014ce3 VFED..CL. .F...... 56,646-1384,804 #7f0d0096 app:id/etEmailLogin}
09-11 03:00:24.567 32751-398/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Both two Toasts shows the same content as:

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{b014ce3 VFED..CL. .F...... 56,646-1384,804 #7f0d0096 app:id/etEmailLogin}
```

Also, please let me know why this is appearing:

```
Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Thanks for your kindness.

UPDATES:
After adding `getText()`s, and `onCompleteListener`, the messages shows:

```
09-11 07:36:28.969 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[LoginActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=157.06055, y[0]=2073.6719, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=37033032, downTime=36201038, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 07:36:28.969 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[LoginActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=157.06055, y[0]=2073.6719, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=37033032, downTime=36201038, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 07:36:28.969 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[LoginActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=157.06055, y[0]=2073.6719, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=37033032, downTime=36201038, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 07:36:28.969 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[LoginActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=157.06055, y[0]=2073.6719, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=37033032, downTime=36201038, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 07:36:31.559 30405-30416/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12136(1617KB) AllocSpace objects, 54(1220KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 9MB/12MB, paused 6.324ms total 111.816ms
09-11 07:36:31.770 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app D/***LoginActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:8cG1dBsCFlNDAWiQHXAN4NSaulN2***
09-11 07:36:36.797 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[WelcomeActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=153.06152, y[0]=2073.6719, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=37040855, downTime=37035146, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 07:36:36.797 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[WelcomeActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=153.06152, y[0]=2073.6719, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=37040855, downTime=37035146, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 07:36:36.797 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[WelcomeActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=153.06152, y[0]=2073.6719, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=37040855, downTime=37035146, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 07:36:36.797 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/ViewRootImpl[WelcomeActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=153.06152, y[0]=2073.6719, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=37040855, downTime=37035146, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
09-11 07:36:42.688 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
09-11 07:36:45.336 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
09-11 07:36:45.966 30405-30405/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app D/LoginActivity: ***android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{2ad64b4 VFED..CL. ........ 56,646-1384,804 #7f0d0096 app:id/etEmailLogin}***
09-11 07:36:45.983 30405-30444/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for ***com.google.firebase.auth not found.***
09-11 07:36:45.983 30405-30444/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
09-11 07:36:56.234 30405-30444/com.example.loyalfine.myponda.app W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: Add a completion listener to `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` to see why the sign-in is failing.  Use [this example code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L150-L172) from the QuickStart project.

Comment: Yes, I did  add a completion listener to signInWithEmailAndPassword(). The result was the same. And it seems the problem comes just after onCreate method is launching....

Comment: What was the failure exception logged by this statement: `Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException())`?

Comment: ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL is the Exception

Comment: Did you first create the user account with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`?  Do you see the account listed at the Firebase console for your project?

Comment: Yes, the Firebase console shows the user email that I am trying to login, which I just registered from the RegisterActivity in the same app.  Which means registration working fine, but not login.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that everything looks good in the Firebase console (accounts are there, etc...)

Right now there doesn't seem to be any code to handle the case where the sign-in isn't successful. I just implemented a sign-in with Firebase in my app, so here's the code I use when a user presses the sign-in button. (Note: I've just noticed a bug where the button is not set to clickable again before the return statements, but other than that everything is fine)

```
//    authenticates user, and starts main activity if successful
@OnClick(R.id.login_button)
public void login(View view) {

//        prevents the user launching the main activity multiple times if their login is valid
    loginButton.setClickable(false);

    String email = null;
    String pass = null;


    //        prevents null entries for email
    if (usernameInput.getText().length() != 0) {
        email = usernameInput.getText().toString();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Please enter your email",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    //        prevents null entries for pass
    if (passwordInput.getText().length() != 0) {
        pass = passwordInput.getText().toString();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Please enter your password",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }


//        signs in with the entered email and pass
    AuthManager.firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
//                        sign in success
                    Log.v(TAG, "signIn:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

//                        if sign in is successful, pass auth info to global variables, and launch intent and start the main activity
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        AuthManager.user = AuthManager.firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        AuthManager.userUID = AuthManager.user.getUid();
                        AuthManager.loggedIn = true;
//                            creates the DB manager to make initial and future DB calls
                        new DBManager();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Signed in",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startMainActivity();
                    } else {
//                            if sign in fails
                        Log.w(TAG, "signIn", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Incorrect username or password",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                            makes the button clickable again
                        loginButton.setClickable(true);

                    }

                }
            });

}
```

I also use a custom AuthManager class in my implementation, but the way you set up your FirebaseAuth object is perfectly fine for it to work.

Comment: The user shows in the Firebase Console correctly. OnCompleteListener was added before, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

The returned exception code, `ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL`, indicates that the string you are passing as the email address to `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` does not have the format of a valid email address.

Check your `logcat` output to see what is logged for `Log.d(TAG, emaill)`.  If it appears to you to be a valid address, please post the value.

**Update:**

The problem is these statements:

```
final String passwordl = etPasswordLogin.toString().trim();
final String emaill = etEmailLogin.toString().trim();
```

you want something like this:

```
final String passwordl = etPasswordLogin.getText().toString().trim();
final String emaill = etEmailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
```

**Update 2:**

After you made the suggested corrections, your `signin()` method should look like this:

```
public void signIn() {
    final String passwordl = etPasswordLogin.getText().toString().trim(); //NOTE addition of getText()
    final String emaill = etEmailLogin.getText().toString().trim(); //NOTE addition of getText()

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, user.getEmail()+"; "+    (findViewById(R.id.etEmailLogin)).toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, emaill);

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emaill, passwordl);
    Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
};
```

The output of `Log.d(TAG, emaill)` should be the valid email address you entered, something like `myName@domainName`.  If the log output is not the email address you entered, post the value that is logged and re-post your code for `signin()`.

Comment: The Log.d(TAG, email) shows: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{b014ce3 VFED..CL. .F...... 56,646-1384,804 #7f0d0096 app:id/etEmailLogin}

Comment: I tried getText() before. and the result was the same.

Comment: have you tried just getText().toString()? I had some issues with the format of this at first, but I've found that this works...

Comment: What does  `Log.d(TAG, email)` produce when you use getText()?  The email should have a format something like `someName@domainName`.

Comment: Yes, when apply getText(), the Log.d(TAG, emaill) produce the right user's email address as wished.  And what I can do next?

Comment: However, if I add onCompleteListener, it showed again as: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{b014ce3 VFED..CL. .F...... 56,646-1384,804 #7f0d0096 app:id/etEmailLogin}

Comment: Your update confuses me.  This line shows you have successfully signed-in: `onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:8cG1dBsCFlNDAWiQHXAN4NSaulN2`.  So it's working now, right?

Comment: Also, this log message is not significant: _Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found_.  It is not an indication of a sign-in failure.

Comment: No, the signed in user was previous user, not the one I am trying to login. It is checking onAuthStateChanged status, and it is before login button clicked. Shall I force the current user to log out before another user to login? Or. is there any thing that I didn't set correctly for multiple users to login?